# Trouble installing nbformat module from terminal, plus how do I reduce amount of troubleshooting (breaks flow) I encounter as a beginner?

Tags: terminal, directory

I forked and cloned a repo from github, opened it in vscode and ran a file. module mentioned was missing, tried installing in the standard way from terminal and received the error below

On a 'macro' note, I have done 2 cs classes in uni but it was an insulated experince, meaning since assignments were given in a neat way there were few problems with imports or having to use github or terminal. Now that I'm trying to learn on my own from github 'courses' I'm running into so many unfamiliar things - github, terminal usage, directories and their permission and accessibility issues, jupyter notebooks - that I cant enter a flow where I'm learning code, so it feels hard that you're making progress since 90% time gets taken up browsing how to solve an issue or learn how to use something.

```
(base) my_name_gmail.com@Name-MacBook-Pro ~ % !pip install pip3 install nbformat
pip install nbformat install pip3 install nbformat
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (5.9.2)
Collecting install
  Downloading install-1.3.5-py3-none-any.whl (3.2 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip3
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
(base) my_name_gmail.com@Name-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Comment: Where you are running and trying to install is having issues signaled by, "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable". Then where that it is doesn't have `pip`. I'd suggest installing [the Anaconda Distribution](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/index.html) then launch the Anaconda Navigator and launch Jupyter from there.  Jupyter includes `nbformat` as part of it and so no need to install. If you do that, always use `%conda install` inside notebooks to install things to the proper environment. Only fall back to `%pip install` run in a cell as backup.

Comment: If you want to make it easy though and not install things on your own machine, then go to https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements and press `launch binder` to get a temporary Jupyter session on a remote computer. It will also have nbformat included when launched in a session. You can clone repos from in the **terminal** with `git clone ...`. (It should also allow `!git clone ...` in a notebook, I suppose.) Then you can run scripts in the terminal of the session or use `%run my_script.py` in a notebook. The session is temporary so save anything useful back to your local computer.

Comment: <continued> In a MyBinder session you can use `pip` in the terminal of the active session and the magic variant `%pip` when inside the notebook. No need for `pip3` these days as that was distinguish it from `pip` running under Python 2 which is typically not an issue much now. You said you were learning in an 'insulated' scenario before. Obviously that wasn't ideal as you quickly encountered issues as you try to apply things in the real world. However, you then turn around at the end of your post & complain about the situation now. Keep plugging away & it will be easier soon.